# custom format to display negative numbers including sign

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, string

I am trying to display hours in a specific format like

1. 8.0 ->>00008.00
2. 8.5 ->>00008.50
3. 9.55->>00009.55

   For this I am simply using below c# statement

String.Format("{0:00000.00}", this.Hours)

But when the hours are negative I am trying to display in below mentioned format

1. -8.0 ->>000-8.00
2. -8.5 ->>000-8.50
3. -9.55->>000-9.55

just to replace one of the zero with minus(-) sign.Please help me to find out a way to achieve the same

Comment: Your code works fine for me (formats `-8.0` as `"-00008.00"`)

Comment: @fubo, Oops - didn't read that too well :) - Would need to be `"{0:00000.00;000-00.00}"` then

Comment: @fubo, Just drop the extra `0` - `"{0:00000.00;000-0.00}"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke then i works for positive hours and negative hours below 10 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should solve it

```
string result = String.Format("{0:0.00}",  this.Hours).PadLeft(8, '0');
```